# jQuery remove last table column

Tags: jquery, html-table

I currently have a table that can be N columns and N rows. In the interface I have a button to remove the last column, but I can't figure out how to remove the last `td` from all the rows, what I've achieved so far is to remove the first row `td`and the last row `td`, but leave the others there.

Here is my code (only deletes the last title currently):

```
function removeTableColumn() {
    /*
        removeTableColumn() - Deletes the last column (all the last TDs).
    */
    $('#tableID thead tr th:last').remove(); // Deletes the last title
    $('#tableID tbody tr').each(function() {
        $(this).remove('td:last'); // Should delete the last td for each row, but it doesn't work
    });
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That's because the [:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector only matches the last element in the set.

You might be looking for [:last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/), which matches the elements that are the last child of their parent:

```
$("#tableID th:last-child, #tableID td:last-child").remove();
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `:last-child` selector, nice!

Answer (score 8):

`:last` returns the last element found by the selector. So `#tableID tr td:last` would return only one `td`.

You can select the last td of each tr be doing this:

```
$('#tableID tr').find('th:last, td:last').remove();
```

Comment: It works perfectly, but I dont' understand what the code does. For each row it gets the children td and th, but what does slice do?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove any column from a table like this

```
    //remove the 1st column
     $('#table').find('td,th').first().remove();

    //remove the 1st column
    $('table tr').find('td:eq(1),th:eq(1)').remove();

   //remove the 2nd column
   $('table tr').find('td:eq(1),th:eq(1)').remove();

   //remove the nth column
   $('table tr').find('td:eq(n),th:eq(n)').remove();
```

for [reference](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-remove-table-column-by-column-number/)